# Ordering Group of records

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the following class

```
class Country
{
   string CtryID {get; set;}
   List<City> city {get; set;}
}

class City
{
   string county {get; set;}    
   int sqkm {get; set;}
}
```

I want to order the result like this

Here's is some sample data for Country and City

**Country**

US
UK
Canada

**City**

CityC
CityF
CityA
CityB
CityG
CityD
CityE

I want to order the records by Country and then City (assuming some cities belong to respectivce countries) and print them like this

**Canada**
CityA
CityB
CityE

**UK**
CityG
CityF

**US**
CityC
CityD

and so on

Comment: What is your data source? A list of cities? Or countries? It seems odd that you'd have no way of getting from a city to its country without checking for each country whether it's in that country's list of cities...

Comment: No a list of Countries..like this new Country() {                    CtryID = "US", cty = new List<City>
{ new City() { county ="CityF", sqkm = 2803 },

Comment: I have a CountryList   List<Country> countries = new List<Country>() If this is not right way of doing, then how should the classes be?

Comment: Don't forget to flag your favorite answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on the technology you use how to display this. For instance, are you using a ASP.NET web site, Windows Forms or Console Application. Are you using a O/RM tool or in-memory collection. Here is an example using in-memory objects, with LINQ, in a Console Application:

```
IEnumerable<Country> countries = GetCountries();

foreach (var country in countries.OrderBy(c => c.Name))
{
    Console.Write(country.Name + " ");

    foreach (var city in country.Cities.OrderBy(c => c.Name))
    {
        Console.Write(city.Name + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Please note that I changed your object model for this. A gave `Country` a `Name` property, gave `City` a `Name` property and renamed the `city` property to `Cities`.

---

You can also do this:

```
var countriesNames =
    from country in countries
    order by country.Name
    let cityNames = country.Cities.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToArray()
    select new
    {
        Name = country.Name
        Cities = string.Join(" ", cityNames)
    }

foreach (var country in countriesNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(country.Name + " " + country.Cities);
}
```

Comment: Ok any way to avoid foreach loop in LINQ? and write it like --     from Co in countries
from ci in Co.City
orderby Co.CtryID, ci.county

Comment: I updated the answer and added a new example that shows a solution without the inner `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like your class structure and what John Skeet said in the comment is true. You should listen to him. He has a big reputation. :)

At the very least you should change to the following:

```
class Country
{
   string CtryID {get; set;}
   List<City> cities {get; set;}
}

class City
{
   string CityID {get; set;}
   int sqkm {get; set;}

}
```

Populate as you said in your comment (but change this to a database or xml file some time):

```
List<Country> countries = new List<Country> { new Country() { CtryID = "US", cities = new List<City> { new City() { CityID  ="CityF", sqkm = 2803 },...etc
```

Then, when you have a populated object graph do the following to get your output:

```
countries.ForEach(ctry => {
     Console.Write(ctry.Name + " ");
     foreach (var city in ctry.cities)
     {
         Console.Write(city.Name + " ");
     }
     Console.WriteLine("");
});
```