# Calculate average in each group

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the following class

```
class Country
{
   int CountryID {get; set;}
   List<City> city {get; set;}
}

class City
{
   int CountryID {get; set; }
   string city {get; set;}  
   int sqkm {get; set;}
}
```

Here's is some sample data for Country and City

**Country**

US
UK
Canada

**City**

CityC
CityF
CityA
CityB
CityG
CityD
CityE

I am populating using

```
List<Country> countries = new List<Country> { new Country() { CountryID = "US", city = new List<City> { new City() {CountryID = "US", City  ="CityF", sqkm = 2803 }, and so on
```

**Question 1:** I want to use LINQ to find avg sq. km of land per country

Eg:

Canada - 2459
UK -  3243
US - 3564

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var countryAvgs = countries
    .Select(c => new { Id = c.CountryId, Area = c.city.Average(ct => (double)ct.sqkm)});
```

Comment: Thanks so so much..it worked...can you help me on this thread too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872617/ordering-group-of-records using expression syntax

Comment: You used c.city.Average here..what if using similar query, I want to access c.city.sqkm?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this (`using System.Linq;`):

```
foreach( Country c in countries)
{
  int average = c.city.Sum( city => city.sqkm)/c.city.Count();
  // display it, or save it, or something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
countries.Sum(x => x.city.Sum(y => y.sqkm)) / countries.Sum(x => x.city.Count())
```

Seems to work ok in LinqPad !